How to style slotted child elements in Astro Layout?
I'm building out my company's blog post page and am having some trouble styling slotted content that comes from my markdown blog posts.
Specifically, I want add some top padding to all child  elements within the  that are part of the blog post body.
What I've tried so far:

Simply setting h2 { padding-top: 50px } to the BlogPost layout's <style>
tag. I figured this would be follow Astro's rules for scoped styling. But it had no effect on the element/page.

Tried .prose h2 { padding-top: 50px }. Still no effect on the element.

I tried doing ::slotted(h2) { padding-top }, and for sure thought that would it. Still nothing.

I also used the :is-global, is-global(), and :is-inline directives in a separate <style> tag with only the target element. Nada.


I included screenshots of my markup, associated stylesheet, and the rendered page view for context.

Blog Post Astro Layout

Blog Post Markdown File

Live Blog Post Webpage
What am I missing here?
Thank you in advance,
David

I'm not an SME but where in your code so you open the slot, perhaps I'm missing it?

Please don't post screenshots of your code. Also, why do you think ::slotted would work? never heard of that being supported in Astro. Look at the docs, but pretty sure it's called e.g. :global(h2)

Hey @mb21,
Sorry, I only included the screenshots to provide better visual context since I wasn't sure how well understood the broader SO community would understand the Astro environment.
I figured I'd try ::slotted given the elements are nested inside of a <slot/> and Astro doesn't interfere with the CSS spec, it only adds little helpers and syntactic sugars around it, if anything.
I've read the full Astro docs, and tried is:global() directive as well as is:inline() for good measure.
Turns out it might be my Layout page shell.
Stay tuned. Thank you!
